# angular to append a template on click of button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to append some html to the existing container through angular directives. here is the code what i have written for the same.

```
app.directive("addActivityRow", function($compile){
var template = "Some html template"
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element,attrs,controller){
        element.on("click", function() {
            console.log("clicked on add row");
            element.parent().append(template);
        });
    }   
}
});
```

here is the html markup

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" addActivityRow class="add" title="Add Row"></a>
```

Can any one please help me in correcting the error what i have done ? When i click on anchor tag, nothing happens, nothing logs on console.

I am new to Angular please help ..

Comment: Typo? `addActivityRow ` should be `add-activity-row ` in the view. Directive names are used as dash-limited attributes in the [view](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Y2CAjrPEmeDR7mq3Sw3?p=preview).

Comment: that worked, thanks PSL. Now i have another question. anchor tag with attribute 'add-activity-row' will be sitting in template as well. How can i bind the directive to click event on dynamically generated element ?

Comment: should i go for $compile() ?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

with this:

```
href=""
```

And use add-activity-row instead of addActivityRow as @PSL mentioned that directive names are used as dash-limited attributes in the view.

---

```
<a href="" add-activity-row class="add" title="Add Row"></a>
```

Comment: thanks for jumping in Bhojendra sah.. i tried removing "javascript:void(0);". when i clicked, it took me to root url.

Comment: use e.preventDefault();

Comment: Here is the logs from my console.

i tried adding twice and deleting twice. when i clicked on delete on the second time. console is showing 3 rather than 2. after that, when i clicked on add, it appended 5 elements.

2 clicked on add row app.js (line 138)
3 clicked on delete row